# kdb how to aj with the first time of appearance

Tags: kdb

Here is my problem:

I have two tables:

```
q)t1:([]sym:1 5;x: 90 90)
q)t2:([]sym: 2 3 4 6 7 8; y: 100 200 300 400 500 600)
```

If I do `` aj[`sym;t2;t1] ``, all the 6 columns in the result table will contain x with value 90.

But what I want is value 90 in column x only in row with `sym` 2 and 6, i.e the first time that `sym` in table `t2` appear before table `t1`.

In other words, I want the result table to be like this:

```
q)([]sym:2 3 4 6 7 8; y: 100 200 300 400 500 600; x:90 0N 0N 90 0N 0N)
sym y   x
----------
2   100 90
3   200
4   300
6   400 90
7   500
8   600
```

Could anyone tell me how I can achieve this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if aj can be used in this sense. This might give you what you need:

```
q)t2 lj 1!update sym:{x x binr y}[t2.sym;sym] from t1
sym y   x
----------
2   100 90
3   200
4   300
6   400 90
7   500
8   600
```

Uses binr to find the next value greater than the value in t1 then joins only on that.

EDIT: note also that binr is >= ..... If you need *strictly* greater than you could use:

```
q)t2 lj 1!update sym:{x 1+x bin y}[t2.sym;sym] from t1
sym y   x
----------
2   100 90
3   200
5   300
6   400 90
7   500
8   600
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do aj to get the index where nearest smaller number of x will fit in, then a vector condition to get x when that index has got incremented, i.e.

```
select sym, y, x:?[c>prev c;x;0n] from aj[`sym; t2; update c:i from t1]
```